# Restructure excel tabular data in python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a huge excel table that I work in Python.

A sample:

| Date | id_m00 | mprice | id_m01 | mprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | aa-bb-cc | 12,05 | dd-ee-fr | 8,80 |
| 02.01.2023 | aa-dd-ee | 09,55 | ff-gg-gg | 7,50 |

This column pattern follows 46 times more. Like `id_m02` and `mrpice`, `id_q1` and `mprice`...

What I want to have is:

| Date | id | mprice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | aa-bb-cc | 12,05 |
| 02.01.2023 | aa-dd-ee | 09,55 |
| 01.01.2023 | dd-ee-fr | 8,80 |
| 02.01.2023 | ff-gg-gg | 7,50 |

Any idea how to do that in Python? I used `melt` function (for the first time) but couldn't do it well. It ended up with some extra columns and lots of `null` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution with [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) :

```
prices = (df.pop("mprice").pipe(lambda x:
      x.set_axis(range(len(x.columns)), axis=1)))

out = (
    pd.lreshape(
        pd.concat([df, prices], axis=1),
        {"id": df.filter(like="id_m").columns, "mprice": prices.columns})
)
```

*NB : The code above can be simplified if the example you shared correspond to the actual table in the spreadsheet. If so, while making the initial DataFrame, pandas will make sure to de-duplicate the `mprices` and will give `mprices.1`, `mprices.2`, .. `mprices.46`* :

```
out = (
    pd.lreshape((df:=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")), # << feel free to adjust
        {"id": df.filter(like="id_m").columns,
         "mprice": df.filter(like="price").columns})
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         Date        id  mprice
0  01.01.2023  aa-bb-cc   12.05
1  02.01.2023  aa-dd-ee    9.55
2  01.01.2023  dd-ee-fr    8.80
3  02.01.2023  ff-gg-gg    7.50
```

Comment: Nice one, I also immediately though of `lreshape` when reading the question, that's indeed the most straightforward if the columns are non-duplicated ;)

Comment: Thanks mozway ;) I tend to forget about it but when I remember that it exists, I use it.

Answer (score 2):

First replace duplicated columns names by counter in [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add for `mprice` values, so possible pass to [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
n = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.columns).cumcount().astype(str).str.zfill(2)

df.columns = df.columns.where(df.columns != 'mprice', df.columns + n)
print (df)
         Date    id_m00 mprice00    id_m01 mprice01
0  01.01.2023  aa-bb-cc    12,05  dd-ee-fr     8,80
1  02.01.2023  aa-dd-ee    09,55  ff-gg-gg     7,50

out = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                     stubnames=['id_m','mprice'], 
                     i=['index','Date'],
                     j="Number")
          .sort_index(level='Number', kind='stable')
          .droplevel([0,2])
          .reset_index())
print (out)
         Date      id_m mprice
0  01.01.2023  aa-bb-cc  12,05
1  02.01.2023  aa-dd-ee  09,55
2  01.01.2023  dd-ee-fr   8,80
3  02.01.2023  ff-gg-gg   7,50
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have always pairs of columns, you can simply set aside the extra columns, split in two the pairs, [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and join again:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Date')

out = (tmp
    .iloc[:, ::2].unstack().reset_index('Date', name='id')
    .assign(mprice=tmp.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy().ravel('F'))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

If you have more that just `Date` as extra column:

```
extra = ['Date', 'other']
tmp = df.set_index(extra)

out = (tmp
    .iloc[:, ::2].unstack(list(range(len(extra))))
    .reset_index(extra, name='id')
    .assign(mprice=tmp.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy().ravel('F'))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
         Date        id mprice
0  01.01.2023  aa-bb-cc  12,05
1  02.01.2023  aa-dd-ee  09,55
2  01.01.2023  dd-ee-fr   8,80
3  02.01.2023  ff-gg-gg   7,50
```